# vertical alignment for children div tag

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [vertical alignment of elements in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div)

I have div tag, in him i have img tag, div tags sizes is static: 200x200, img sizes is always less than 200px, but how exactly, I dont know beforehand. I want img will be alwasy center of the div tag, in horizontal I make, but how to make this as vertikal ?

```
   <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: #090; text-align: center; ">
        <img src="pic.jpg">
    </div>
```

Comment: Please see the related questions to the bottom right of this page.

Comment: Please tell me, how to make vetikal alignment when beforehand I dont know children element height? In general this is possible ?

Comment: Check out the duplicate question he linked to, or just look at this: http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Look at [this JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/amiregelz/ZfHmL/3/)

You can use the CSS [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/-moz-calc) function to vertically center an image inside the div:

```
position: relative;
top: -webkit-calc(50% - []px )    /* [] = half the image height) */;  
top: calc(50% - []px)    /* [] = half the image height) */;
```

Comment: Thanks but, you tests this metod? this works incorrectly

Comment: I want set children element in center for parent element as vertikal. In your code, children element top border is in center and not self children element. is not it?

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how you can fix it so it will be exactly in the center. You could do it manually if you'd use `px` instead of `%` and you know you image height, but this way it's even easier.